# i18n in Android

Tags: android, internationalization

How it possible in android i18n means multi language. i want to developed application that support Hindi language but when i found about android i18n all tutorial said that add new resource like **value-hi** in this folder add new string.xml. but my problem is that how to write in Hindi in string.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the Hindi character set is not supported by Android, yet.

See: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1618

Comment: You can verify this by opening the following URL with Android and looking at the sample text section: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Hindi#Sample_text